# Как узнать какой подкласс скрывается за ссылкой на базовый класс

Tags: c++, наследование, класс

Есть класс узла, который может иметь родительский и дочерние узлы.
У него есть метод для получения дочернего узла по его имени

```
Node& Node::getChild(std::string name)
{
   //...
}
```

От класса узла можно наследовать другие подклассы.
Но в данной ситуации неизвестно какой конкретный подкласс скрывается за базовым классом.

Как узнать что именно скрывает возвращаемая ссылка?

Сделать метод виртуальным не вариант...

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что  он может возвращать ссылку только на базовый класс?  Ссылаться можно на любой класс из иерархии  Node. Только его нужно предварительно объявлять

Comment: Упс, немного не правильно сформулировал вопрос, уже исправил

Comment: `dynamic_cast`? Но лучше все-таки прикрутить вирутальный метод.

Comment: Необходимость выяснять, какой подкласс скрывается за ссылкой (посредством `dynamic_cast` или еще как) обычно говорит о неправильно построенной иерархии классов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от того, в каком виде вы хотите получить информацию о производном классе. Если нужно знать совпадает ли тип с каким-то конкретным наследником, чтобы использовать методы этого наследника, то достаточно использовать `dynamic_cast`.

Если нужно просто идентифицировать наследника, то [может помочь](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yLgySjX41baqKmZJ) оператор `typeid`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct B {
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct D : B {};

struct FF : B {};

int main()
{
    B& ref1 = *new D;
    B& ref2 = *new FF;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    try {
        dynamic_cast<D&>(ref1);
        std::cout << "ref1 is D\n";           
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "ref1 isn't D\n";
    }

    try {
        dynamic_cast<D&>(ref2);
        std::cout << "ref2 is D\n";
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "ref2 isn't D\n";         
    }    

    std::cout << typeid(ref1).name() << "\n";  
    std::cout << typeid(ref2).name() << "\n";  
}
```

Вывод:

```
ref1 is D
ref2 isn't D
1D
2FF
```

Строки, возвращаемые через `typeid::name` не являются стандартизированными, но на уровне определённого компилятора можно добиться подходящего результата. В данном случае видно, что строка состоит из числа, задающего кол-во символов имени, и последующего за ним имени.

При всём этом не стоит забывать, что и `typeid` и `dynamic_cast` для работы требуют наличия хотя бы одной виртуальной функции в базовом классе. В моем примере для этого выбран виртуальный деструктор.

Comment: Думаю стоит также особо отметить, что практика подобных кастов - это очень плохая затея и скорее указывает на ошибки проектирования, которые решаются другими способами. А то ТС наверняка будет использовать этот подход направо и налево...

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых то что вы хотите невозможно, во-вторых не нужно. Дело в том, что подобные проблемы решаются с помощью паттерна `visitor`.

Comment: Поясните за что минус?